# How to SELECT string between second and third instance of ",,"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get string between second and third instance of ",," using SQL SELECT.
Apparently functions substring and charindex are useful, and I have tried them but the problem is that I need the string between those specific ",,"s and the length of the strings between them can change.
Can't find working example anywhere.

Here is an example:

> **Table:** test
> **Column:** Column1
> **Row1:** cat1,,cat2,,cat3,,cat4,,cat5
> **Row2:** dogger1,,dogger2,,dogger3,,dogger4,,dogger5
> **Result:** 
> cat3
> dogger3

Here is my closest attempt, it works if the strings are same length every time, but they aren't:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column1,LEN(LEFT(column1,CHARINDEX(',,', column1,12)+2)),LEN(column1) - LEN(LEFT(column1,CHARINDEX(',,', column1,20)+2)) - LEN(RIGHT(column1,CHARINDEX(',,', (REVERSE(column1)))))) AS column1
FROM testi
```

Comment: Store these values in own table, storing multivalues like this is way to hell.

Comment: Use nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` (in MySQL).

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server` ?

Comment: @Squirrel I am using SQL Server.

Comment: @pavel The way these values are stored isn't up to me.

Comment: Find out who it is up to, and educate them on how to store data in databases!

Comment: @Jamiec They know how to. This is special occasion.

Comment: Even [`STRING_SPLIT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can only take a single char separator.

Comment: @DaleK I added my closest attempt.

Comment: I corrected the example, I used the word column when I meant row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just repeat sub-string 3 times, each time moving onto the next ",," e.g.

```
select

  -- Substring till the third ',,'
  substring(z.col1, 1, patindex('%,,%',z.col1)-1)

from (values ('cat1,,cat2,,cat3,,cat4,,cat5'),('dogger1,,dogger2,,dogger3,,dogger4,,dogger5')) x (col1)
-- Substring from the first ',,'
cross apply (values (substring(x.col1,patindex('%,,%',x.col1)+2,len(x.col1)))) y (col1)
-- Substring from the second ',,'
cross apply (values (substring(y.col1,patindex('%,,%',y.col1)+2,len(y.col1)))) z (col1);
```

And just to reiterate, this is a terrible way to store data, so the best solution is to store it properly.

Comment: Thnak you. How do you use this if I want all of the values of column1? There you have written the values.

Comment: I got it. Now it works just as I wanted. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using `charindex`. The base idea is the same as in Dale K's an answer, but instead of cutting the string, we specify the start_location for the search by using the third, optional parameter, of `charindex`. This way, we get the location of each separator, and could slip each value off from the main string.

```
declare @vtest table (column1 varchar(200))

insert into @vtest ( column1 ) values('dogger1,,dogger2,,dogger3,,dogger4,,dogger5')
insert into @vtest ( column1 ) values('cat1,,cat2,,cat3,,cat4,,cat5')

declare @separetor char(2) = ',,'

select
    t.column1
    
    , FI.FirstInstance
    , SI.SecondInstance
    , TI.ThirdInstance
    , iif(TI.ThirdInstance is not null, substring(t.column1, SI.SecondInstance + 2, TI.ThirdInstance - SI.SecondInstance - 2), null)
from
    @vtest t
    cross apply (select nullif(charindex(@separetor, t.column1), 0) FirstInstance) FI
    cross apply (select nullif(charindex(@separetor, t.column1, FI.FirstInstance + 2), 0) SecondInstance) SI
    cross apply (select nullif(charindex(@separetor, t.column1, SI.SecondInstance + 2), 0) ThirdInstance) TI
```

For transparency, I saved the separator string in a variable.
By default the `charindex` returns 0 if the search string is not present, so I overwrite it with the value null, by using `nullif`

Comment: Thank you. I will test this method too.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, SQL Server 2016 and its JSON support in the best option here.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Tokens VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES 
('cat1,,cat2,,cat3,,cat4,,cat5'),
('dogger1,,dogger2,,dogger3,,dogger4,,dogger5');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT * 
       , '["' + REPLACE(Tokens
          , ',,', '","')
          + '"]' AS jsondata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT rs.ID, rs.Tokens
    , JSON_VALUE(jsondata, '$[2]') AS ThirdToken
FROM rs;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------------------------------------------+------------+
| ID |                   Tokens                    | ThirdToken |
+----+---------------------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | cat1,,cat2,,cat3,,cat4,,cat5                | cat3       |
|  2 | dogger1,,dogger2,,dogger3,,dogger4,,dogger5 | dogger3    |
+----+---------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It´s the same as @"Yitzhak Khabinsky" but i think it looks clearer

```
WITH CTE_Data
AS(
    SELECT 'cat1,,cat2,,cat3,,cat4,,cat5' AS [String]
    UNION
    SELECT 'dogger1,,dogger2,,dogger3,,dogger4,,dogger5' AS [String]
)

SELECT 
     A.[String]
    ,Value3 = JSON_VALUE('["'+ REPLACE(A.[String], ',,', '","') + '"]', '$[2]')
 FROM CTE_Data  AS A
```